# How to make a loop in return so that not to repeat scrapy.request?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a page. I tried to make loop in `return` function but it didn't work. It gave me the result of just first link. I want to make a loop so that I could return all three values.

```
class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'

    def start_requests(self):
        links = {'transcription_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription',
                 'captions_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions',
                 'subtitles_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/subtitles'}
        call = [self.parse_transcription, self.parse_caption, self.parse_subtitles]

        return [
            scrapy.Request(links['transcription_page'], callback=call[0]),
            scrapy.Request(links['captions_page'], callback=call[1]),
            scrapy.Request(links['subtitles_page'], callback=call[2])
        ]
```

Comment: Apart from formatting, I'm not sure what is wrong with your code. It looks like it will return a list of three items.

Comment: I want to make a loop in it. I know that is correct but I don't want to repeat ```scrapy.Request``` again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a list comprehension do the looping so that there is only one instance of the text `scrapy.Request()` in the program, but of course being a loop the function will be called once per loop:

```
class SiteFetching(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Site'

    def start_requests(self):
        links = [('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription', self.parse_transcription),
                 ('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions', self.parse_caption),
                 ('https://www.rev.com/freelancers/subtitles', self.parse_subtitles)]

        return [scrapy.Request(link[0], callback=link[1]) for link in links]
```

Another option if you want to avoid making all the requests at once and waiting for them all to return is to use a generator expression:

```
        return (scrapy.Request(link[0], callback=link[1]) for link in links)
```

**btw I know nothing about Spider etc**

Now you call `start_requests()` but it returns a generator and you call `next()` on it to make each `Request()`:

```
sf = SiteFetching()   # I assume this is how you instantiate SiteFetching
gen = sf.start_requests()   # Only returns a generator
req = next(gen)   # Only here does the first call to Request() occur with callback to follow.
```

I only showed one instance of calling `next()`, but you could have a loop (or iterate over it with for), but any way you do it you get to say when the `Request()` occurs and what you do before and after each call.

Comment: What about using `yield` within a loop instead of returning a list? I think that’s what the OP is looking for.